# Java make file reader account for specific letters

Tags: java, filereader, account, letter

Well I'm almost finished with my world editor thanks to this great community, the only thing I need to know is how I can tell my read File code to process specific letters. When I hit enter on my keyboard I will write coordinates of a Vector3f to a text file, this Vector3f is the posistion of my active GameObject. My ProcessText method can read a text file and process the coordinates however he can only read ony type of format:

```
public void ProcessText()
     {      
        String file_name = "C:/Users/Server/Desktop/textText.txt";

        try
        {           
            ProcessCoords file = new ProcessCoords(file_name);
            String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(aryLines[i]);    

                 if(aryLines[i].startsWith("makeGrass:")) {
                        String Arguments = aryLines[i].substring(aryLines[i].indexOf(":")+1, aryLines[i].length());
                        String[] ArgArray = Arguments.split(",");

                        this.makeGrass(Double.parseDouble(ArgArray[0]), 
                                       Double.parseDouble(ArgArray[1]), 
                                       Double.parseDouble(ArgArray[2]));                    
                }
            }   
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
     }
```

In the above example my ProcessText method can only process the coordinates if they are written like this:

```
makeGrass:x,y,z             //for example makeGrass:5,1,9
```

But when I press enter and write the coordinates from what me my engine gives I'm getting a different format:

```
makeGrass:(x y z)           //for example makeGrass:(3 1 4)
```

Now what I need to know is how I have to rewrite the code in my ProcessText method so it accounts for the other format that has brackets at the beginning and end and also with spaces to sepearta x from y and y from z instead of commas.

I really don't knwo where else I would find an answer to this question so I'd apreciate any help and explanation as to how this works.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `ArgArray = Arguments.substring(1, Arguments.length() - 2).split(" ");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to accept as many formats as possible?

Instead of splitting I would try to match, this is safer and doesn't need any pre- or post-processing of the input or the received substrings:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)"); // outside of method

long[] ArgArray = new long[3];
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Arguments);
int i = 0;
while (matcher.find() && i < 3) {
   ArgArray[i++] = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));
}
// there was a mistake if i < 3, otherwise you have 3 numbers in ArgArray
```

If you want to split, you could maybe try this: `split("[^0-9]+")`

**To only match makeGrass:(x y z)**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^makeGrass:\\(([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)\\)$");
```

Like this you can directly match the line and have the 3 numbers in groups 1 - 3 (as String) after calling `find` once, `if (matcher.find())` will decide if it's a valid makeGrass line and if so it can be processed in the `if`.

Comment: No I don't want to accept as much formats as possible only makeGrass:(x y z) is necessary but I'm also interested in how it works because in the future I might want to write to and read from a file other things than just some coordinates like in this case. But thanks for the hint!

Comment: @DisasterCoder ok, I added another version, it's just regex (the \ has to be doubled because it's also the escape character in Java Strings).

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out as soon as possible, just one thing: the numbers are floats, usually the coordinates will be something like (1.23333 1.56665 5.88769) or something simmilar.. will this still work if you only declare from zero to nine?

Comment: @DisasterCoder no, then use `([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)`, if there is always just one digit before the . then you can remove the first `+` and if there have to be exactly 5 digits after the . then replace the 2nd + by {5}

Comment: or if the 2nd part is optional `([0-9]\\.?[0-9]*)`

Comment: Yes, just realized my method is Double.parseDouble but your example accounts for Long.parseLong - how do I deal with that?

Comment: @DisasterCoder it is the same, first you create the matcher from the line, then you look if (matcher.find()) and then you can get the 3 double values with `Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1))` (and 2, 3), group 0 is the whole match in this case the entire line.

Comment: @DisasterCoder if you only need something that works, see my comment under your question, that's all that needs to be done. But I made a mistake with the substring, it's -1 and not -2.

Comment: Oh thanks, I got it to work now, didn't see your comment there, thanks! There's now another problem though.. didn's consider that but I'm only rendering the first position. hmm.. well, I'm gonna have to work on that for a while.. but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

if you can guarantee that there will not be any spaces in the makeGrass:x,y,z format and that there will not be any parenthesis in it either then you can use String.replaceAll()...  Something like below:

```
myString = "makeGrass:(3 1 4)"
myString = myString.replaceAll("\(", ""); //replace ( with empty space
myString = myString.replaceAll("\)", ""); //replace ) with empty space
myString = myString.replaceAll(" ", ","); //replace spaces with commas
```

then you don't need to different methods to handle the two types of input. just format as shown above and pass both inputs to the same method

Going this way you will not need to split on certain chars and then rebuild the string to fit your format

Comment: I don't really understand what you're telling me, do you sugest I change the way how the coordinates are being written to the file? Because if so then I have to say this would be a lot more complicated than I think it should be.. but maybe you can show me how you think ths piece of code fits into my ProcessText method because I don't really understand how I should implement your code..?

Comment: so your program would read the input in, lets say the input is the incorrect format of makeGrass:(3 1 4)... then you would use the above posted 4 lines and that would turn your input into the correct format of makeGrass:3,1,4 then you can go about processing it as you did before

Comment: I don't think this would work that easily since writing to a file works with this code here: data.writeToFile("makeGrass:" + (GetTransform().GetPos())); To get the coordinates I am using the Transform class of my engine which has acess to the Vector3f methods. I don't think I am experienced enough to implement your idea into my code..

Comment: or maybe I'm just being confused - sure will try it out.. thanks!

Comment: yes it's the same here.. I'm getting the error that I've used the wrong type of ending sequence the error is marked around the sings \(  don't know how to solve this..?

Answer (score 0):

Just split with the regular expression : `[\s,]`
Splits the String at places where there is either a `white space` or a `,`.

And use this to get rid of any brackets if present :

```
Arguments = Arguments.replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "");
```

`(` and `)` are part of regex notation. So, they need to be escaped with `\` and `\` being a Java notation, needs to be escaped with another`\`. Hence it becomes `"\(". And we have to replace the string and store it back to the String variable. Because Java is pass by value. Both the operations are done in the same line.

**The modified code for the method is :**

```
public void ProcessText() {      
     String file_name = "C:/Users/Server/Desktop/textText.txt";



public void ProcessText()
 {      
    String file_name = "C:/Users/Server/Desktop/textText.txt";

    try
    {           
        ProcessCoords file = new ProcessCoords(file_name);
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(aryLines[i]);    

             if(aryLines[i].startsWith("makeGrass:")) {
                    String Arguments = aryLines[i].substring(aryLines[i].indexOf(":")+1, aryLines[i].length());

                    Arguments = Arguments.replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "");

                    String[] ArgArray = Arguments.split("[\\s,]");


                    this.makeGrass(Double.parseDouble(ArgArray[0]), 
                                   Double.parseDouble(ArgArray[1]), 
                                   Double.parseDouble(ArgArray[2])); 
            }
        }   
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Okay, but does this also account for the brackets? It's makeGrass:(x y z) not just makeGRass:x y z .. but thanks for the hint!

Comment: Hi there, I think this might work but your code gives me an error: Arguments.replaceAll("\(", ""); it says invalid naming sequence..?

Comment: I have made the correction. And have checked it too. This will work. Sure. It was my mistake. I overlooked putting 2 \s. I put only 1 previously. it needed to be escaped.